# Short Story Identification: Man in the middle ages who is in a group mind with his descendants

Tags: story-identification

30 years ago I read a scifi story that I'm now trying to track down.  It involved a man back in the middle ages who one day realizes that him and a baby share one mind --- he literally is in both bodies.  Over time, his descendants become a group mind and slowly take over most of the world, until they encounter a similar group mind.  The minds then each take to the stars.

Does this story sound familiar to folks?

Comment: I've read the 2nd one, but I am not sure I can turn it up.

Comment: May you edit the question to focus on one of these works (ideally the one that has already been answered), and ask the other separately?

Comment: You can always post the apple question as a separate one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ["Let's Be Frank" by Brian Aldiss](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41215). An [online copy](https://lexal.net/scifi/scifiction/classics/classics_archive/aldiss2/aldiss21.html) (with terrible formatting) is available.

> Strangely perturbed, as if something inexpressible lay just below the surface of his thoughts, Sir Frank went over to the bed and rested his hands on the boy's shoulders. He seemed to stand on the brink of a precipice.
>
> "Frank," he whispered—for the sleeping child had been given his own name—"Frank, why don't you wake up?"
>
> In answer to the words, the youth's eyes opened. The usual wash of dizziness came and went like a flash; Sir Frank found himself looking up into his own eyes. [...]
>
> "What sorcery is this?" Sir Frank muttered.
>
> But it was no sorcery, or not in the sense Sir Frank meant. He had merely acquired an additional body for his ego. It was not that he could be in either as he pleased; he was in both at the same time. When the son came finally to consciousness, it was to his father's consciousness.